# unable to create jar file of web application using maven

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to create jar file of web application. but it is creating war file only.I also update `<packaging>jar</packaging>`

but not working

pom

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>XertoPublicApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>XertoPublicApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>C:\Users\musaddique\workspace\XertoPublicApp\src</sourceDirectory>
        <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\Users\musaddique\workspace\XertoPublicApp\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>C:\Users\musaddique\workspace\XertoPublicApp\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>C:\Users\musaddique\workspace\XertoPublicApp\target\classes</outputDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>C:\Users\musaddique\workspace\XertoPublicApp\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>C:\Users\musaddique\workspace\XertoPublicApp\src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>C:\Users\musaddique\workspace\XertoPublicApp\src\test\resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <directory>C:\Users\musaddique\workspace\XertoPublicApp\target</directory>
        <finalName>XertoPublicApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>           
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-war</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <outputDirectory>C:\Users\musaddique\workspace\XertoPublicApp\target\site</outputDirectory>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Putting in the pom and project structure will help others understand what the problem might be

Comment: Also how do you execute maven ? If you use maven-war plugin it will create a war.

Comment: I want jar file, contain all classes

Comment: i tried will maven-jar plugin also

Comment: Oh god, your POM is awful. Please keep the default values and never override `<sourceDirectory>` or `<testSourceDirectory>` and others...! Do yourself a favour!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the maven-war-plugin, this causing the war to be output.
If you can remove this plugin and you should start getting a jar.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `maven-war-plugin` in the `plugins` which is creating a `war` file and add [`maven-assembly-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) with `descriptorRef` `jar-with-dependencies` if you need all the dependent classes.

```
          <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove maven-war-plugin from your pom.xml